# How to manually call query (e.g. on click) using Vue Apollo Composible?

Tags: composition, vue-apollo

The default behavior is that useQuery is loaded immediately with component setup.

I want to trigger the query on some event like click.

How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i searched for it a lot too, but it is writtin in their documentation [vue apollo v4e](https://v4.apollo.vuejs.org/guide-composable/query.html#refetching)

```
import { useQuery, useResult } from '@vue/apollo-composable'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

export default {
  setup () {
    const { result, loading, error, refetch } = useQuery(<query>)

    const users = useResult(result)

    return {
      users,
      loading,
      error,
      refetch,
    }
  },
}
</script>

<template>
  <div v-if="loading">Loading...</div>

  <div v-else-if="error">Error: {{ error.message }}</div>

  <ul v-else-if="users">
    <li v-for="user of users" :key="user.id">
      {{ user.firstname }} {{ user.lastname }}
    </li>

    <button @click="refetch()">Refresh</button>
  </ul>
</template>
```

just add the "refetch" to the useQuery line and call it from the button click event.

EDIT: You could disable the query, so it wont trigger on component setup and on button click you could enable the query and refetch it.

Best Regards